# Ruby on rails User registration using rest API call and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mobile, devise, restful-authentication

Can anyone guide me how to register a user from mobile device (rest API) in ruby on rails. I'm using Devise with Rails 3.0.

it is giving me this following error

NameError in Devise::CustomRegistrationsController#create

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've override the functionality of devise registration controller with the following.

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|  
    format.html { 
      super 
    }
    format.json {
      build_resource
      if resource.save
         render :status => 200, :json => resource
      else
        render :json => resource.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity
      end
    }
  end
 end
```

this solved the problem and I've added

```
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create
```

to avoid authenticity check.

Comment: How do you add the route for this?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to make views for mobile than make an app on android/iOS? If you need API, then go with POST requests at /users/sign_up (and similar), for example,
browse localhost:3000/users/sign_up and change form's action parameter to `action="/users.json"`, then click submit and you will receive the API's response, for me (on vanilla setup):

`{"email":["has already been taken"],"password":["doesn't match confirmation","is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]}`

This way you can debug API (which follows standard conventions) with your browser. Notice that only `:format` parameter changes on rails routes (you can choose `.json` or `.xml` for APIs response)

POST info sent by my browser:

`"utf8=✓&authenticity_token=n5vXMnlzrXefnKQEV4SmVM8cFdHDCUxMYWEBMHp9fDw%3D&user[email]=asd%40fasd.org&user[password]=321&user[password_confirmation]=1233&commit=Sign+up"`