# Rails + Devise + API + User Registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, mobile, devise, registration

I am new to ruby and rails and so far I managed to setup user management using devise. Right now I am trying to integrate support for mobile Android and iOS apps. So far it is possible for them to login and logout and get an authentication token. But in addition to that I would also like them to be able to register.

Now, as I understand it I have to do a post to

```
http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up
```

How does this post look like? And how do I get a JSON response? I found this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666871/ruby-on-rails-user-registration-using-rest-api-call-and-devise).

```
"utf8=✓&authenticity_token=n5vXMnlzrXefnKQEV4SmVM8cFdHDCUxMYWEBMHp9fDw%3D&user[email]=asd%40fasd.org&user[password]=321&user[password_confirmation]=1233&commit=Sign+up"
```

Unfortunately this does not work - I am getting the message "Bad request". I also do have a couple of questions about this example. What is the authenticity_token for? How do I get one? This is not the devise token authentication I guess as the user is not even in a position to have one at this point.

Also, after a successful login I would like to bundle the "registration successful" message with a generated devise authentication token. So I guess I have to somehow extend devise`s existing registration controller.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Devise already has all this setup. Based on your signup path, I infer that you mounted Devise onto `http://localhost:3000/users`. Devise includes all the controllers and views that are required, including the log in form, the sign up form, the email confirmation form and the password reset forms.

GET `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up` is actually a form for users to signup at. The form on that page will POST to `http://localhost:3000/users/`, which goes to Devise's registration controller's create action.

Assuming there is no action/view already at `/users/sign_up`, the sign up form should be there, go check if it is there (assuming you set up `devise_for` correctly in your `routes.rb` file).

Comment: thanks for the clarification. My sign_up view is available. The sign up post to /users/ is working now. The response looks like this: {"created_at":"2012-09-07T12:59:51Z","email":"asd@fasd.org","id":3,"updated_at":"2012-09-07T12:59:51Z"}

I would like to receive a devise authentication token in this response so the user can mobile app can use this token when accessing the api. How to go about that? I guess I have to overwrite devise´s registration controller?

Comment: If you want the controller to do something different or extra, you can override devise controllers - info at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers.